# How would I add margin-bottom using jQuery

Tags: jquery, margin

Here's the code I am using that fixes a `div` to the top of the page while scrolling but I want to give the `div` a `margin` after it gets fixed to the top.

```
var fixmeTop = $('.fixme').offset().top;
$(window).scroll(function() {
    var currentScroll = $(window).scrollTop();
    if (currentScroll >= fixmeTop) {
        $('.fixme').css({
            position: 'fixed',
            top: '0',
            left: '0'
        });
    } else {
        $('.fixme').css({
            position: 'static'
        });
    }
});
```

I've seen examples such as this to add margin using jQuery, but I can't get it to apply to my code:

```
$('.fixme').css('margin-bottom',90);
```

You'll see that when the `div` gets fixed to the top of the page the space between the two elements closes up. I want to add `margin` to the `div` after so that it has the same distance as soon as it sticks.

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/zu75wpqm/)

Comment: $('*') targets all elements on the page. I assume you just want to apply this to the fixme class?

Comment: When you fix an element (i.e. `position: fixed`) you don't need margins around it, because that will serve no purpose. What you need in the stead is padding on body.

Comment: Sorry, I get you now! I havent used fixed positioning in about 6 months and completely forgot it loses it "block" style properties. Maybe there is a way I can add margin-top to the element below the div that becomes fixed and move that down instead? would still work just as well for me, I just don't know how to do it with jQuery

Comment: Omg! that add class worked perfectly! thank you that was just what I needed

Comment: @Abhitalks add that fiddle as an answer and I will vote it correct

Comment: @SaturnsEye: I have added these comments as an answer. I shall be deleted these comments in a few minutes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> You'll see that when the div gets fixed to the top of the page the
>   space between the two elements closes up. I want to add margin to the
>   div after so that it has the same distance as soon as it sticks.

You can't do that. That's because, once an element is `fixed`, it is removed from the flow and is in a different layer altogether from the rest of your content. Putting margin on `fixed` element will not work because that is in a different layer. Content scrolls past from behind this `div` and there is no way you can control the spacing. Content is going to get covered up by this `div` anyway. Check this fiddle to see what I mean (added shadow to help you visualize the layers):

**Demo Fiddle 1: http://jsfiddle.net/abhitalks/3Lv6fL7r**

If you just want to avoid the abrupt jumping of that `div`, just add `margin-top` to that `div`. Alternatively (*and a better way*), keep those styles in CSS and apply / remove those classes.

**Demo Fiddle 2: http://jsfiddle.net/abhitalks/zu75wpqm/5**

<sub>Note:  You need `marginTop` instead of `margin-top` when you are using that as a property via Javascript.</sub>

Answer (score 2):

You can add the margin bottom in the if statement:

```
    $('.fixme').css({
        position: 'fixed',
        top: '0',
        left: '0',
        marginBottom: '5%' // you can write with quotes "margin-bottom" too
    });
```

Comment: Yes it does. Inspect it and you can see the margin-bottom. However, it's not your solution. Position fixed can't fix the other content with a margin.

Comment: What you need to achieve? The code is working fine. If you need to view the content just at the bottom of the sticky div, you need to make another thing different to fixed positioning.

Comment: I basically want the red div to not jump up to the green div when the green div touches the top of the page. You can see it doing it here if you carefully scroll: http://jsfiddle.net/zu75wpqm/3/

Comment: When you scroll, the red div goes up. This is the correct and normal behaviour. If you need to make the red div in bottom of the sticky, maybe you need to make sticky the red div.

Answer (score 0):

Just add it in your .css function when(if) the div is fixed:

```
var fixmeTop = $('.fixme').offset().top;
$(window).scroll(function() {
    var currentScroll = $(window).scrollTop();
    if (currentScroll >= fixmeTop) {
        $('.fixme').css({
            position: 'fixed',
            top: '0',
            left: '0',
            margin: '5%'
        });
    } else {
        $('.fixme').css({
            position: 'static'
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: I don't want margin all around the div, just margin-bottom but the code seems to ignore that input

Comment: @Wizzard you should update the fiddle ,because I don't believe this works (even though the syntax is correct.